# There is no quasiconformal map from punctured ball into ring (on the plane)

Tags: integration, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

The idea is to use l2 cohomology as a quasiregular map invariant.
It is easy to see that there are closed 1-forms on the ring which are not exact, but it occures that *every* closed l2-form in punctured ball
$f_1(x,y)dx + f_2(x,y)dy$
is exact. Here $f_1$ and $f_2$ are $C^{\infty}(B_1\backslash\{0\})\cap L^2(B_1\backslash\{0\})$ functions. The ball $B_1$ is open.
I have got some problems with the proof.
I want to prove that $\int_{x^y+y^2=r^2}f_1dx+f_2dy=0$ for any $0<r\leq 1$.
Then, as the form is exact, this integral doesn`t depend on radius $r$. So by using the polar coordinates and the previous remark we can write:
$r\int_0^{2\pi}f_2(r,\varphi)\cos(\varphi)-f_1(r,\varphi)\sin(\varphi)d\varphi=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_0^\varepsilon r\int_0^{2\pi}f_2(r,\varphi)\cos(\varphi)-f_1(r,\varphi)\sin(\varphi)d\varphi dr$
This holds for any $\varepsilon>0$. I am trying to get some upper inequalities in order to prove that this is zero but the standart ones seems not to be useful here. Can you help me on that?
If we prove that this is integral is zero and the pullback of differential form saves L2-integrability we get the required contradiction.